# How to use Default variables in airflow

Tags: airflow

How can we use Default variables in `airflow` which are showing in below link 
https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#default-variables

I have used this in my code as shown below:

```
def decide_which_task():

    if {{ dag_run.task_id }}  is  "Move_file":    
            return "move_file"    
        else:    
            return "push_to_db"
```

But i am getting error in log file as

> NameError: global name 'dag_run' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotation you are trying to use is the annotation for Jinja templating within strings.

To use the same variables in a task, you need to:

- use the parameter `provide_context=True` in the `PythonOperator`
- change the function signature to `def decide_which_task(**context):`
- then access the variable out of the context, e.g. `mytask = context['task_id']`

Code:

```
def decide_which_task(**context):

if context['task_id']  is  "Move_file":    
        return "move_file"    
    else:    
        return "push_to_db"
```

Comment: example too basic to get help from the post